# If $\rho(A) \geq \rho(A-B)$? Given that $A$, $B$, and $A-B$ are positive definie matrices.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$, $B$, and $C=A-B$ be positive definite matrices (Highlight: $C = A - B$ is positive definite). Then, I am not sure if the following holds
$$\rho(A) \geq \rho(C),$$
where $\rho(\cdot)$ returns the spectral radius of a matrix.

If it doesn't, is there any counter example?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that $C$ was also positive definite!

Comment: @RideTheWavelet Sorry, I should highlight that $C$ is positive definite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is true. By the Rayleigh-Ritz Theorem, $\rho(A)=\max_{\|x\|=1}x^{*}Ax$ for any positive definite $A$, and thus

\begin{align*}
\rho(A)&=\max_{\|x\|=1}x^{*}Ax\\
&\geq\max_{\|x\|=1}x^{*}Ax-x^{*}Bx\\
&=\max_{\|x\|=1}x^{*}(A-B)x\\
&=\rho(A-B)=\rho(C).
\end{align*}

In fact, $\rho(C)=\max_{\|x\|=1}x^{*}Ax-x^{*}Bx\leq \max_{\|x\|=1}x^{*}Ax-\lambda_{1}(B)=\rho(A)-\lambda_{1}(B),$ where $\lambda_{1}(B)$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $B.$

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks very much for your kind help! (The result $\rho(A) \geq \rho(C) + \lambda_1(B)$ is also much better than I thought) [+1]